# Android - SQL syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite

Here is my code, with unrelated stuff removed:

```
public class DataManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private final static String DB_TABLE = "Nums";
    private ContentValues initialValues;
    private static SQLiteDatabase myDB;

    public DataManager()
    {
        initialValues = new ContentValues();
        if(null != myDB)
        {myDB.close();}
        myDB = getWritableDatabase();   // This causes NullPointerException which is next on my TODO list
    }

    public void addValues(String num, String val)
    {
        initialValues.clear();
        initialValues.put(num,val);
        myDB.insert(DB_TABLE, null, initialValues); // THIS LINE CAUSES ERROR
    }
}
```

I can `CREATE` the database but I can't `INSERT` without getting this error:
`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "1": syntax error: , while compiling: INSERT INTO Nums(1) VALUES(?);`

The database table `Nums` looks like this:

```
Num | Val
=========
1   |   23
2   |   34
3   |   6
4   |   3
5   |   5
6   |   56
7   |   34
8   |   45
9   |   32
10  |   23
```

As you can see, I'm trying to create a database with a list of numbers from 1 -> n where each number has a value beside it. All values in the database are `String`. There was a reason I didnt choose `INT` but cant remember now.... :(

Can anyone see where my syntax is wrong?
My phone is rooted so I can use an SQLite Browse app to view the database, and the table is created, its just empty!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for put is ContentValues.put(columnName, value). Try the following code.

```
public void addValues(String num, String val)
{
    initialValues.clear();
    initialValues.put("Num",num);
    initialValues.put("Val",val);
    myDB.insert(DB_TABLE, null, initialValues); 
}
```

Just as some helpful suggestions, you don't need to save a reference to myDb. You can just always call getWritableDatabase() inside of your SqlLiteOpenHelper.

Comment: Ah ok, ye so I was obviously using it wrong. Makes sense now, thanks!